# Visual Studio 2015 not generating binaries

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have Visuaal Studio 2015 Update 2. But none of the projects that I built generate binaries in the `bin` folder. Not even new projects.

It compiles fine, the output window says:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: EfCoreTest2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But no files are generated. I also can't run the Web API project (a new project), because no `bin` files are generated. So with other words, it has no files to run...

I did a VS2015 Repair, but that didn't solve it.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: Is your project building successfully? Did you try looking at the build output window to see where it says it put the binary?

Comment: They are not generated into the bin folder.  Are you sure you know where to look?

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe not. I am under the impression that a default Web API project produces files in the `bin` directory. Where else would the files go?